# Preventing People from Not Inputting with prompt()?

Tags: javascript, prompt

With the `prompt();` method in JavaScript, if a `prompt();` window keeps popping up, there's an option to "prevent this page from creating further dialogues." I have a page where I need the user to input something specific, an if they don't the page prompts them to ask it again. Is there a way to make the `prompt();` window pop up indefinitely?

```
console.log("Thanks!");
```

Comment: Thankfully, no, else bad sites would be able to make navigation difficult. `prompt` is extremely user-unfriendly, use a proper modal instead.

Comment: I think you should create your own prompt in your site, you can use `modal` if you use `bootstrap` or something like that.